# Complex selection query from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I need to select records for review based a nutty set of factors primarily from two tables, supplementing additional data from a third. here are the factors:

- is it annual, and not overridden? (stays annual)
- OR it is NOT annual, BUT IS overridden? (WAS biennial, but now is annual)
- OR does the searchYear match the even/oddness of the recordYear?

  - (this handles biennial cases that would qualify for the searchYear)
- AND finally does it match the searchQtr? (because this is a quarterly summary)

so based on that, here's my query that i've assembled (and is throwing an error):

```sql
select ar.id as eNum, ar.quarter as qtr, dd.description as device, ar.building_name AS bldgName, ir.inspectorName
from (select * from asset_roster) ar
join device_descriptions dd on ar.descriptionID = dd.id
left join inspector_roster ir on ar.inspectorID = ir.id
where ar.id not in ( select eNumber from safety_report )
and ( ( (dd.annual = '1' and ar.override = '0') or 
        (dd.annual = '0' and ar.override = '1') ) or
      ( (select mod( left(ar.quarter,2))) = '1') )
and ( right(ar.quarter,2) = 'Q2' )
group by bldgName asc;
```

so this query fails with this message:

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near ')) = '1') ) and ( right(ar.quarter,2) = 'Q2' ) group by bldgName asc' at line 8
```

some things to note:  the query up to the first `and` works on it's own.  and the last `and`, above the `group by...` works as well.  so I've narrowed it to the group of nested `and`s.  sadly, I'm unable to unravel exactly what the issue is here.  which is why this post now exists.

Comment: `mod()` requires 2 parameters https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_mod.asp

Comment: *facepalm*... thank you.  SMH... what a dumb oversight...  :P  so busy counting bracket, didn't think to double-check that... upside: rest of query is good.  again, thank you.

Comment: There is no advantage to `from (select * from asset_roster)` over `from asset_roster`

Comment: And the way you're storing quarter must be horribly inefficient

Comment: oh yes. the clowns who built the db I'm working with are something else... that's the tip of the iceberg... 